# Jquery select all if not disabled

Tags: jquery, select, checkbox

I am using the following script to select all checkboxes with a given class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // 1
    // 2
    $(':checkbox.selectall').on('click', function(){
        // 3
        $(':checkbox[class='+ $(this).data('checkbox-name') + ']').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
        $(':checkbox[class='+ $(this).data('checkbox-name') + ']').trigger("change");
    });

});
```

However I'm having a problem as the de/select all checkbox is able to de/select checkboxes which are disabled.

I tried this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // 1
    // 2
    $(':checkbox.selectall').on('click', function(){
        // 3
        $(':checkbox[class='+ $(this).data('checkbox-name') + !$(:disabled) + ']').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
        $(':checkbox[class='+ $(this).data('checkbox-name') + !$(:disabled) + ']').trigger("change");
    });

});
```

But it does not work. I have made a jsfiddle to showcase the problem http://jsfiddle.net/e67Fv/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Hm... interresting attempt, but you can't use a jQuery object inside a selector, as the selector is just a plain string.

The selector for excluding the disabled elements would be `:not(:disabled)`, so your code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(':checkbox.selectall').on('click', function(){
    $(':checkbox[class='+ $(this).data('checkbox-name') + ']:not(:disabled)').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
    $(':checkbox[class='+ $(this).data('checkbox-name') + ']:not(:disabled)').trigger("change");
  });
});
```

Note that you can chain calls, so you don't have to select the items twice:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(':checkbox.selectall').on('click', function(){
    $(':checkbox[class='+ $(this).data('checkbox-name') + ']:not(:disabled)').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked")).trigger("change");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Use a combonation of the `.not()` function and `:disabled` selector to exclude these.

```js
$(':checkbox[class='+ $(this).data('checkbox-name') + ']').not(':disabled').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
$(':checkbox[class='+ $(this).data('checkbox-name') + ']').not(':disabled').trigger("change");
```

`.not()` also exists as a selector as `:not()` and could be used as follows:

```js
 $(':checkbox[class='+ $(this).data('checkbox-name') + ']:not(:disabled)').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
 $(':checkbox[class='+ $(this).data('checkbox-name') + ']:not(:disabled)').trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I usually do:

```
$(function(){
    $(".selectall").live('change', function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            $("input:checkbox:not(:disabled)." + $(this).data('checkbox-name')).prop("checked", "true");
        }
        else
        {
            $("input:checkbox:not(:disabled)." + $(this).data('checkbox-name')).prop("checked", "false");
        }
    });
});
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Hm... Did you read the question? This only does part of what the original code did. There is nothing in there to handle the disabled checkboxes.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that in the code, I just edited my answer adding :not(:disabled)...

Answer (score 3):

This does not do the same as your original code. It would only trigger change for those that was not changed. I've assummed you wished to trigger change for all the once you changed

```
$(':checkbox.selectall').on('click', function(){
        $(':checkbox .'+ $(this).data('checkbox-name')).not(':disabled').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked")).trigger("change");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery supports [`:enabled`](https://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/) since `v1.0`

`$('input:checkbox:enabled')`

is the same as

`$('input:checkbox:not(:disabled)')`

and helps avoid the `:not()` selector.